# Allowing a restricted user (rbash) and to run virsh

Tags: bash, ssh, virtual-machine

We have a virtual win7 machine that needs to be rebooted remotely from time to time. We created a restricted user account with the shell set to rbash so a user can ssh in and reboot the virtual machine via virsh when needed.

```
user@machine:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/rbash
user@machine:~$ virsh
Welcome to virsh, the virtualization interactive terminal.

Type:  'help' for help with commands
       'quit' to quit

virsh # list
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: no valid connection
error: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': Permission denied
```

virsh and virt-top do run, but the user can't do anything inside virsh. How can we allow this user to run virsh commands from an rbash shell?

Comment: I think this is not `rbash` related, but an ordinary permission-problem.  The user in question has to have read/write permissions on the socket it tries to open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer, as using ssh to connect to the host, and then using a dedicated user running `rbash` seems only a workaround to me.

As a less hackish alternative to one could simply connect remotely to libvirtd via [`virsh`](http://libvirt.org/sources/virshcmdref/html-single/).
See e.g. https://libvirt.org/uri.html and [especially the section about remote URI's](http://libvirt.org/uri.html#URI_remote)

Answer (score 1):

Andreas is correct, it is not an rbash problem; adding user to the group libvirtd solves the problem.

Comment: FWIW, as an alternative to the ssh + rbash approach you could simply connect remotely to libvirtd via `virsh` - see e.g. https://libvirt.org/uri.html and especially the section about remote URI's: https://libvirt.org/uri.html#URI_remote

Comment: The comment from @doktor5000 should be the accepted answer.